# How do I make a non-breakable paragraph?

Tags: tables

According to [this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Non-breaking_spaces) I can use `~` to make a non-breaking space. But how do I make a non-breaking paragraph?

Example:

```
Have a look at this table:

\begin{table}[h]
   ... contents ...
\end{table}

Next step is to ...
```

Here, LaTeX made a page break where the table was supposed to be, meaning the output went like this:

```
 Have a look at this table:

 Next step is to ...

 (table contents)
```

Comment: that is the (only) purpose of the `table` environment, to mark the content as a float that can be moved to help page breaking. You should refer to it indirectly via its caption number rather than assuming it is in a specific place in the document. not `look at this table:` but `as shown in table \ref{mytable}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Fair point. I will use indirect referral instead. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: must be a duplicate:-), I'll find one...

Comment: perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned